# Unexpected token operator (>) UnityWebGL

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, webgl

I'm trying to build unity webgl but I'm getting error "unexpected token operator > "
Does anyone know how I could make unity understand this (=>) operator or does anyone know how to replace this operator?

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {

  SaveStats : function (data) {
    var dataString = UTF8ToString(data);
    var obj = JSON.parse(dataString);
    player.setData(obj);
  },

 // LoadStats : function(){
 //   player.getData().then(_date => {
  //    const myJSON = JSON.stringify(_date);
  //    Game.SendMessage('Progress', 'Load', myJSON);
 //   });
 // },
  LoadStats : function(){
   player.getData().then(function(_date){
    const myJSON = JSON.stringify(_date);
    Game.SendMessage('Progress', 'Load', myJSON);
  });
  },

  SetToLeaderBoard: function (value) {
    ysdk.getLeaderboards()
    .then(lb => {
      lb.setLeaderboardScore('Points', value);
    });
  },

  ShowAd : function(){
    ysdk.adv.showFullscreenAdv({
      callbacks: {
        onClose: function(wasShown) {
          console.log("-----closed------")
        },
        onError: function(error) {
          // some action on error
        }
      }
    })
  },

  ShowRewardedAd : function(){
    ysdk.adv.showRewardedVideo({
      callbacks: {
        onOpen: () => {
          console.log('Video ad open.');
        },
        onRewarded: () => {
          console.log('Rewarded!');
          Game.SendMessage("Canvas","AddDollars");
        },
        onClose: () => {
          console.log('Video ad closed.');
        }, 
        onError: (e) => {
          console.log('Error while open video ad:', e);
        }
      }
    })
  },

  ShowAdRiviwe : function(){
    ysdk.adv.showRewardedVideo({
      callbacks: {
        onOpen: () => {
          console.log('Video ad open.');
        },
        onRewarded: () => {
          console.log('Rewarded!');
          Game.SendMessage("Scripts","UnLose");
        },
        onClose: () => {
          console.log('Video ad closed.');
        }, 
        onError: (e) => {
          console.log('Error while open video ad:', e);
        }
      }
    })
  },

  GetLang: function () {
    var lang = ysdk.environment.i18n.lang;
    var bufferSize = lengthBytesUTF8(lang) + 1;
    var buffer = _malloc(bufferSize);
    stringToUTF8(lang, buffer, bufferSize);
    return buffer;
  },

});
```

I tried to rewrite the code myself in order to get rid of this operator, but I'm not selenium in javascript and therefore I don't know if I wrote the code correctly :(

Comment: "unexpected token operator > " is mostly the result form the server, where the scripts is not found, so you get a 404 page like <html> and thats not json.

Answer (score 1):

Unity 2021 and older uses old version of uglify-js lib. Its JavaScript parser can't parse lambda functions.
Rewrite JavaScript code without using lamba functions:

```
var print = (str) => {
    console.log(str);
};
```

to:

```
var print = function(n) {
    console.log(str);
};
```

or update the project to Unity 2022.2, which uses a newer version of uglify-js